# Imagem não aparece React-native

Tags: imagem, react-native, image

Estou iniciando em React-native, então estava fazendo um App assistindo um video, e quando fui colocar uma imagem ela não apareceu, coloquei dentro de uma pasta, e quando vou colocar o caminho da imagem não aparece nada. Já tentei de tudo, mas fiz igualzinho ao que o cara do video fez.
Link do video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSV4fsaVTIs&t=2101s

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Image } from 'react-native';



export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image source={require('./src/assets/logo.png')}/>
      <Text>ADSASDAaS</Text>
    </View>
  )
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#f3f3ff'
  }
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

duas soluções a primeira mais longa mas acredito ser a mais certa pois você define o tipo do import.

**1. Usando Import:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Image } from 'react-native';
...
import logo from './src/assets/logo.png';
```

e chamar a imagem

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Image source={logo}/>
  <Text>ADSASDAaS</Text>
</View>
```

o erro aconteçe pois o typescript ele não encontra a tipagem do .png
como eu resolvo aqui é assim

- na pasta src crio uma pasta chamada

> @types

- depois crio um arquivo chamado

> png.d.ts

e escrevo dentro dele

```
declare module '*.png';
```

quando você salvar é para funcionar no celular, pode ser que no navegador não apareça ai é só definir um estilo para a imagem:

```
<Image style={styles.image} source={logo}/>
```

e o estilo:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
  flex: 1,
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  backgroundColor: '#f3f3ff'
 },    
 image: {
  width: '100%',
  height: 360,
 },
});
```

**2. Usando let**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Image } from 'react-native';
...
let logo = require('./src/assets/logo.png');
```

e chamar a imagem

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Image source={logo}/>
  <Text>ADSASDAaS</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Reinaldo, seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Por favor, adicione mais informações à sua resposta explicando como ela resolve o problema do post original e pode, também, adicionar informações de referência, como documentações.

Answer (score -2):

Bom dia.
Faz o seguinte: 
adiciona nos imports 
 
import logo from './src/assets/logo.png';

depois passe na sua imagem: 
< Image source={logo} />

Espero ter ajudado. Fico a disposição.

Comment: Já tentei mas não funcionou também, mas consegui colocar imagem usando uri e um link da internet. Mt estranho, vou investigar mais pra tentar descobrir o porque não consigo colocar uma imagem local.